# Get parent div of event when document is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom

I have a header on my website, the header has a "button" that has a Icon and also some text.
When you click this "button" it will show or hide an extra menue on the page by toggeling the visibility of a class.

```
<div id="header_wrapper">
    <div id="header_area">
        <a class="noSelect" href="#">
            <div id="favuorites_header_wrapper" class="header_item">
                <div id="favuorites_header_font" class="noSelect">Open Menue</div>
                <div id="favuorites_header_icon" class="noSelect"></div>
            </div>
        </a>   
    </div>
    <div id="hidden_favuorite_area_wrapper">
        <div id="hidden_favuorite_area">Your personal area</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content_wrapper">foo</div>
```

Now I want to hide this menue again, when you click outside the header or menue area.

I tried

```
$(document).click(function(event){
    if(event.target.id =="content_wrapper"){
        // hide
    }
});
```

But event.target.id returns the ID of the clicket element only, not the parent.
How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you show more code.

Comment: Highly invalid html except HTML5 - use spans instead

Comment: Do you want `$('#myElement').click(function(){ alert($(this).parent().attr('id')); });`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to stop propagation of the click event within the element.

```
$(document).click(function(event){
  // hide
});

$("#header_wrapper, #menu_wrapper").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This will stop event bubbling beyond these elements.  In this way, any click within `#header_wrapper` or `#menu_wrapper` (or whatever your menu is called) will not trigger the document's handler.

Comment: This will still propagate when you click the header or the button. Is there something wrong with my structure?

Comment: Based on your html this will not propagate to the document level when the header area or button (in the header area) are clicked.  It will propagate only as far as the wrapper where it will be stopped.

Comment: Then obviously there is a problem with my structure because $('#content_wrapper').click(function(){ alert()}); won't work

Comment: Perhaps you can create a demo on jsfiddle or jsbin.  It seems you have bigger issues.

Comment: I solved the issue and your code is running fine. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
  if ($(event.target).is('#content_wrapper *')) {
    // click somewhere inside content wrapper
  }
```

To be safe you'd probably want to check for the wrapper itself:

```
  if ($(event.target).closest('#content_wrapper').length) {
    // click in the wrapper, or on the wrapper itself
  }
```

Comment: unfortunately nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You could bind an event at the moment the button gets clicked, and unbind it when something is clicked thats not inside the header.

The .parent() function takes a selector. This way you can check if an element is inside another one.

```
$(function() {
    // The selector of the button that gets pressed
    $('#favuorites_header_font').on('click', function() {

        // Insert your [toggle to visible] code here

        $(document.body).on('click.hidemenu', function(event) {
            // Check if the clicked element is outside the header
            if( $(event.target).parent('#header_area').length === 0 ) {
                // Its outside, unbind the (namespaced, to not destroy other code) event.
                $(document.body).off('click.hidemenu');


                // And insert your [toggle to hidden] code here
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
$(document).click(function(event){
 el=event.target.id;
 if($("#"+el).parent().get(0).id=="content_wrapper"){
   //hide
}

});
```